# Prove characterization of the finiteness of $E \left[ |X| \right]$ by the behaviour of expectations $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{A}\right]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, lp-spaces

I want to prove:

> $E \left[ |X| \right] < \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0 ~\exists \delta > 0  $ such that $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{A}\right]< \varepsilon ~\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $P(A) < \delta$

I have already shown "$\Rightarrow$" but I'm struggling with "$\Leftarrow$".

An idea of mine would be:
Let $ A = \{ |X| \geq n\} $. We have that $ \mathbb{P}(A)= \int \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X| \geq n\}} \mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} \rightarrow 0 $ for $ n \rightarrow \infty $, because $ \{ |X| \geq n\} \rightarrow \emptyset $

This means that $ \exists K \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\mathbb{P}\left(A\right) < \delta ~\forall n \geq K $. 
Thus, $ \mathbb{E} \left( |X| \mathbb{1}_A \right) < \varepsilon $.
Make use of this set $ A $ and consider $ \mathbb{E}\left( |X| \right)$.

$ \mathbb{E}\left( |X| \right) = \int |X| \mathbb{1}_ {\{ |X| \geq n\}} \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} + \int |X| \mathbb{1}_{ \{ |X| < n\}} \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} < \varepsilon +\int |X| \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X| < K\}}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} < \varepsilon + K \int \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X| < K\}}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} \leq \varepsilon + K 
$
This shows that $ \mathbb{E}\left( |X| \right) < \infty ~ \forall A \in \mathcal{F}$ mit $ \mathbb{P}\left( A \right) < \delta$

Is this correct?

---

(First idea, which is wrong: 
"Assume $E \left[ |X| \right] = \infty$. Let $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $P(A) < \delta$. Thus, $ E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{A}\right] = E \left[ |X| \right] P(A) = \infty  $. Contradiction.")

Comment: I think you lost yourself in the contradiction (or I did not understand what you did) because you just end with an upper bound equal to infinity.

Comment: Indeed, the conclusion that $ E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{A}\right] \leq \infty  $ can hardly contradict anything. FYI, $\Leftarrow$ assumes crucially that $P$ has no atom (and I would be curious to see your proof of $\Rightarrow$...).

Comment: @Did: In short: My $\Rightarrow$ uses the P-integrability of X and I basically have $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_A \right] \leq \int_A |X| \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X| \geq N\}} \mathrm{d}P + \int_A |X| \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X| < N\}} \mathrm{d}P$. Then with the THM of dominated convergence the left summand is less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and the right summand is less or equal to $N \cdot P(A)$. Then I choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2N}$ and thus $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_A \right] < \varepsilon$.
I see everything in my $\Leftarrow$ is complete nonsense. Do you have any hints for $ \Leftarrow $?

Comment: I have edited my post, I accidentally copied the wrong line from my notes.

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbb{E}(|X| 1_A)= \mathbb{E}(|X|) \mathbb{P}(A)$....?

Comment: @saz: Because $E \left[\mathbb{1}_A \right] = P(A)$

Comment: So what? $|X|$ is not a constant; you can't simply pull it outside.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that. Do you have any ideas where I can start my proof then?